# Why use Printwriter over PrintStream in Java for outputting human readable text

Tags: java, io, printwriter, printstream

The java documentation says to use Printwriter over Printstream when dealing with text, but why is this so? I know Printwriter deals with character streams and Printstream deals with byte streams but their both bytes at the end of the day. And since Java 1.5 PrintStream has not been limited to using the platform default encoding; there are constructors that accepts a charset name. So what benefit does Printwriter have over Printstream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PrintStream` is ancient. Prefer `PrintWriter`. Actually, it's better to use neither since both classes swallow exceptions silently.

I suggest using an `OutputStreamWriter` wrapped by a `BufferedWriter`.

`PrintStream` cannot use a character encoding other than the default charset. If you need to write strings as UTF-8 bytes and the default JVM charset is Windows-1252 (as is the case when running Java on Windows), then `PrintWriter` can do that, and `PrintStream` cannot. That's the main difference, I think.

`PrintWriter` doesn't allow you to write a `byte[]`, while `PrintStream` does. Allowing direct writing of `byte[]` opens up the possibility of making mistakes by mixing character encodings which shouldn't be mixed.

`PrintWriter` allows you to write a `char[]` directly while `PrintStream` does not.

`PrintWriter` allows you to write a slice of a String without allocating a new String.

Comment: Since Java 1.4, the `PrintStream` class has offered [a constructor that accepts an encoding parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream-java.io.OutputStream-boolean-java.lang.String-), allowing you to specify the character encoding to be used when writing text to the underlying output stream. It is not true to say that `PrintStream` cannot use a character encoding other than the default charset.